# Regex extract substring ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

```
"{\"status\":1,\"redirect\":\"/some/uri/uri2/index.html?post_login=80607979823520\",\"security_token\":\"/cpsess8233434446\"}"
```

I am getting this response as string and I need to extract security_token value.
I tried to convert the string to Hash by eval method.seems not worked and I need to do a regex match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
require 'json'
a =  JSON.load "{\"status\":1,\"redirect\":\"/some/uri/uri2/index.html?post_login=80607979823520\",\"security_token\":\"/cpsess8233434446\"}"
p a["security_token"]  #=> "/cpsess8233434446"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON data..

```
result = "{\"status\":1,\"redirect\":\"/some/uri/uri2/index.html?post_login=80607979823520\",\"security_token\":\"/cpsess8233434446\"}" 
h = JSON.parse(result)
h['security_token']      # => "/cpsess8233434446"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either JSON.load the data and filter for ['security_token'] or use a .match(/security_token/) style regex expression.

I'd suggest the prior for future readability and code maintenance.